# How to start a MapActivity from normal Activity in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I created a launcher `MapActivity` from new project and it is working fine. Now I want start a `MapActivity` from normal activity like `MainActivity.java` to `MapsActvity.java` such that from `MainActivity`, it should send latitude and longitudes values for marker to show in `MapActivity` when a button in the main layout is clicked. I am thinking of using intent but I don't know how do it.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In MainActivity on button click 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActvity.class);
intent.putExtra("latitute", 34.8098080980);
intent.putExtra("longitude", 67.09098898);
startActivity(intent);

In MapActivity.java onCreate method get lattitude and longitude and use it
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        double lat = intent1.getDoubleExtra("latitute", 0);
        double lng  = intent1.getDoubleExtra("longitude",0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer USKMobility, but i had to modify your code to use it :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("latitute", 34.8098080980);
 intent.putExtra("longitude", 67.09098898);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use this

```
 Intent geoIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse("geo:0,0?q=" + address));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Pass the `address`, the above code uses inbuilt Maps and shows the `address` specified.

Place this in your `Manifest` file

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```